# Transposing ggplot2 graph with x-axis at top

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make the transformation shown below.  In particular the **x-axis must also be at the top**.

This is the command for the left hand side graph:

```
ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = xer_filename, y = unpivot_val, group = task_code)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

I'm trying the below *(swapping x and y, and using scale_x_discrete)* but am getting an error I don't understand:

```
ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = unpivot_val, y = xer_filename, group = task_code)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + scale_x_discrete(position="top")
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You could add `+ guides(x = "axis", x.sec = "axis")` for duplicated x-axes at the top and bottom of the panels.

Comment: Thanks! That works and may even be a better solution for readers.

Comment: Just swap the args to x and y in `aes` and specify axis positioning in the standard way. Your x-axis wasn't "discrete"